# How Can I Apply VS Code Keyboard Shortcuts to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

**Preface:**
I'm a long-time user of VS Code for JavaScript and .NET Core. I think it's a great tool and I am extremely productive in it for most of my work. There are times, however, where I need to use Visual Studio 2017 for .NET Framework projects.

**Question:**
Is there a way to import my VS Code keyboard shortcuts into Visual Studio 2017 without manually altering the individual shortcuts in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about in Visual Studio 2017 but in Visual Studio 2019, you can go to:

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and apply the Visual Studio Code Mapping.

It is not a perfect mapping but it gets you most of the way there.  One of the big ones I had to change was Edit.GoToDefinition to be f12

But it works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks! That must've been recently added. It is, in fact, now an option in VS 2017